# DatStage Insert Data From Sequential File to ODBC Stage

Tags: datastage

I would like to use DataStage to insert data into a table.  We receive about 900 tab delimited text files a month.  Each file corresponds to a table. The tables can be broken down into 18 different types, with 1 table fore each type per state. I would like to use DataStage for ths, if possible.  Currently I am having with the insert.  For background, we are currently using simple insert statement sfor this, which has allowed lots of duplicate data to be loaded into th etables.

Currently there is a sequential stage that is directly linked to an ODBC stage.  As for the below SQL, the column names are not the same between the Sequential Stage file and the ODBC stage.  All of the columns from the Sequential Stage are not used.  The load_date and effective_date columns in the ODBC stage are not present in the Sequential Stage.

In the Sequential Stage, the Runtime column propagateion box is checked.

In the ODBC Stage, the Write Mode is set to Insert, Generte SQL is set to NO.  The below SQL is the insert statement.

Columns are not defined in either the Sequential Stage not the ODBC Stage.  I am trying to keep this generic, because this needs to be done for about 900 different tables.

insert into xxx.ak_bop_terr_zip (zip_code, rec_count, iso_comm_territory_code, percentage, load_date, effective_date)
SELECT ORCHESTRATE.ZIP, ORCHESTRATE.RECCNT, ORCHESTRATE.TERR_CODE, ORCHESTRATE.PCT, current timestamp, current date
          from ORCHESTRATE
         where not exists (select 1
                             from xxx.ak_bop_terr_zip
                            where zip_code = ORCHESTRATE.ZIP and rec_count = ORCHESTRATE.RECCNT
                              and iso_comm_territory_code = ORCHESTRATE.TERR_CODE and  percentage = ORCHESTRATE.PCT);

ODBC_Connector_2: Invalid SQL statement parameter name: PCT. It does not exist in the design schema and the connector was not able to describe it (CC_DBRecordDataSetConsumer::setDataSetDef, file /builds/IS_11_3_1_2_RC1/Common_Connectors/Build_Current/CC_Common/DAAPI/build/include/ccl/connector/CC_DBRecordDataSetConsumer.inl, line 665)

I am not sure about the SQL syntax.  Are you allowed to use ORCHESTRATE as I am doing?  Does it need to be done differently?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can not do a correlated subquery uning ORCHESTRATE.  I am now using a different approach of loading the data into a temp table, then using the temp table in the correlated subquery.